# Go+MySql: how easy is to migrate to GKE (Google Cloud Container Engine)?

Tags: mysql, docker, go, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

My project is currently hosted by an independent cloud provider.

I am using 2 Virtual Machines, with Linux:

- one hosts a Go application
- one hosts a MySql database

I would now like to move to the Google Cloud Platform.

Do you think does it make sense to move to Google Cointainer Engine (GKE), rather than to the Google Compute Engine (which would have the same virtual machine model (IaaS) I am using with the current provider)?

I have never used Kubernetes and Docker. How easy would it be to make the migration? Am I going to complicate my life uselessly?

How difficult is the configuration for my simple model?

Comment: Is App Engine standard environment out of the question? Or flex?

Comment: I would like a bit more flexibility than that

Comment: I understand Kubernetes will become the de facto standard for the cloud architecture. But how easy is it to migrate a simple architecture to that?

Comment: What is your motivation for moving in the first place? Why fix something that isn't broken?

Comment: My motivation is to be able to start using some Google Cloud Platform services. I am currently using an independent provider, but I would like to move to Google Cloud. I am considering whether to move to GKE (container engine) or to GCE (compute engine).

Answer (score 0):

> I have never used Kubernetes and Docker.

Moving to a platform that you have no experience with doesn't sound like a great idea. Instead, why not start by doing some tutorials about Docker and then Kubernetes?

After that, you might try Minikube (https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/minikube/) locally to start writing some manifests for the components (which sound like maybe a DaemonSet or single Pod with PersistentVolume for MySQL and a Deployment for the Go application).

Once you have the pieces working locally, then it would probably make more sense to think about migrating. You would have a much better understanding of what you are getting into and if it is something you would want to undertake.

Comment: Thanks Andy, it makes sense what you say. I actually just found out about this very good tutorial made by Google about Kubernetes and Docker: https://www.udacity.com/course/scalable-microservices-with-kubernetes--ud615